# Canada/Chinese dual passport. Currently in the UK as Canadian student. How should I return to China?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, canadian-citizens, chinese-citizens

I was born in China, immigrated to Canada and obtained Canadian citizenship. I did not renounce my Chinese citizenship. After obtaining my Canadian passport, I went back to China for a while. I later returned to Canada via the US. I have a 10-year US visa on my Chinese passport and I used to it to travel to the US. Then I flew to Canada using my Canadian passport. Therefore, the last record on my Chinese passport is me entering the US. While in Canada, I decided to go study in the UK, so I applied for a student visa using my Canadian passport.

Currently I am in the UK as a Canadian international student and have just completed most of my studies. My dissertation is on the Chinese consumer market, so I am planning to return to China to conduct my research. However, I am very confused as to how I could return to China without the Chinese authorities finding out that I have two passports. Which passport should I use to travel?

Answer (score 1):

Travel back to the US first, and enter with your Chinese passport. Get an entry stamp. Then fly to China, using your Chinese passport. You *should* be ok, since the last stamp is the US. Where you're coming apparently from.

However, if the Chinese immigration dud(in)e is awake at the wheel, you might face a few questions, regarding where you were in between.

Flying to China is never 100% safe for dual citizens.

Comment: I'd like to add that flying back is mostly safe, because for Chinese biometric passport holders the entry process is mostly automated. But when you leave China you might be scrutinized.